# Calling Subscribe inside Foreach Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, foreach, rxjs, subscribe

**I've a survey which contains list of questions, where each question contains list of multiple choice answer. I'm trying to push this to my backend, but it's pushing ONLY the first question of the survey according to my database. I made sure that the questions and the answers are inserted correctly and also i tested the mutation using Graphql**

```
this._surveyService.addSurveyToInitiative(this._initiativeId, this.name, this.category, "TBD").subscribe(surveyData => {
     this.survey.questions.forEach(question => {
        this._surveyService.addQuestionToSurvey(surveyData.data.createSurvey.survey.id, question.question).subscribe(questionData=> {
          question.multipleChoiceAnswers.forEach(answer => {
            this._surveyService.addMultipleChoiceAnswerToQuestion(questionData.data.addQuestionToSurvey.newQuestion.id, answer).subscribe()
          })
        })
     })
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the first blush, the problem doesn't appear to be RxJS or `subscribe`. Something about your service calls is likely the culprit. That being said, it's hard to debug.

Nesting `subscribes` and/or calling `subscribe` in a loop is basically always an antipattern. You're mixing imperative and functional programming styles with abandon - that's not to say you can't make it work but that teasing apart what is going wrong (not to mention maintaining/extending this in the future) becomes more challenging.

First lets rewrite this more functionally:

```js
this._surveyService.addSurveyToInitiative(
  this._initiativeId, 
  this.name, 
  this.category, 
  "TBD"
).pipe(
  map(surveyData => 
    this.survey.question.map(question =>
      this._surveyService.addQuestionToSurvey(
        surveyData.data.createSurvey.survey.id, 
        question.question
      ).pipe(
        map(questionData => ({ question, questionData }))
      )
    )
  ),
  mergeMap(serviceCalls => merge(...serviceCalls)),
  map(({ question, questionData }) => 
    question.multipleChoiceAnswers.map(answer => 
      this._surveyService.addMultipleChoiceAnswerToQuestion(
        questionData.data.addQuestionToSurvey.newQuestion.id, 
        answer
      )
    )
  ),
  mergeMap(serviceCalls => merge(...serviceCalls))
).subscribe();
```

Here, this line: `mergeMap(serviceCalls => merge(...serviceCalls))` (Seen twice) is effectively how you subscribe to all your calls.

This should be much easier to debug. Now you can `tap` any part of your stream to see what's happening at that moment.

```js
this._surveyService.addSurveyToInitiative(
  this._initiativeId, 
  this.name, 
  this.category, 
  "TBD"
).pipe(
  tap(surveyData => console.log("Processing surveryData: ", surveyData)),
  map(surveyData => 
    this.survey.question.map(question =>
      this._surveyService.addQuestionToSurvey(
        surveyData.data.createSurvey.survey.id, 
        question.question
      ).pipe(
        map(questionData => ({ question, questionData }))
      )
    )
  ),
  mergeMap(serviceCalls => merge(...serviceCalls)),
  tap(questionAndData => console.log("Processing questionAndData: ", questionAndData)),
  map(({ question, questionData }) => 
    question.multipleChoiceAnswers.map(answer => 
      this._surveyService.addMultipleChoiceAnswerToQuestion(
        questionData.data.addQuestionToSurvey.newQuestion.id, 
        answer
      )
    )
  ),
  mergeMap(serviceCalls => merge(...serviceCalls))
).subscribe(x => console.log("done processing final step, got reponse: ", x));
```

Now you can `delay` certain calls, or use `concat(...` instead of `merge(...` to get a feel for what your stream is doing.

#### Aside:

Here is the same thing, only a bit more concise (We combine our merge calls):

```js
this._surveyService.addSurveyToInitiative(
  this._initiativeId, 
  this.name, 
  this.category, 
  "TBD"
).pipe(
  mergeMap(surveyData => 
    merge(...this.survey.question.map(question =>
      this._surveyService.addQuestionToSurvey(
        surveyData.data.createSurvey.survey.id, 
        question.question
      ).pipe(
        map(questionData => ({ question, questionData }))
      )
    ))
  ),
  mergeMap(({ question, questionData }) => 
    merge(...question.multipleChoiceAnswers.map(answer => 
      this._surveyService.addMultipleChoiceAnswerToQuestion(
        questionData.data.addQuestionToSurvey.newQuestion.id, 
        answer
      )
    ))
  )
).subscribe();
```

#### Update # 1

Are you sure

```
this.survey.question.map(question =>
```

is right? Seems like a strange naming convention. I would expect something more akin to

```
this.survey.questions.map(question =>
```

Comment: Thank you first of all for the help! I tried to run your code and syntactically it works, but in the backend it does same as my code does. So it pushes the first question to the survey without any answers. (this.survey.questions is correct because a survey has a list of question). Thanks again

Comment: Part of the point of my answer was to help you debug. Whatever is going wrong for you is not apparent/visible in your question. You'll have to update your question before you can hope for any further help.

Answer (score 0):

You should not chain subscriptions. Also forEach is a final operation, which means that nothing is returned from it. You should use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) instead.

A better way would be to use [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) to get something like follow:

```
this._surveyService.addSurveyToInitiative(this._initiativeId, this.name, this.category, "TBD")
    .pipe(
        map(surveyData => surveyData.data.createSurvey.survey.id),
        mergeMap(surveyId => this.survey.questions.map(question => this._surveyService.addQuestionToSurvey(surveyId, question.question))),
        map(questionData => questionData.data.addQuestionToSurvey.newQuestion.id),
        mergeMap(questionId => question.multipleChoiceAnswers.forEach(answer => this._surveyService.addMultipleChoiceAnswerToQuestion(questionId, answer)))
    ).subscribe();
```